error with UndefVarError: `Optimizer` not defined
I am trying to use JumP and Ipopt under Julia v1.10.5. When I try to construct a model:Model(Ipopt.O optimizer）
I get the following error message:
UnderVarError:OG=Model(Ipopt,Optimizer)
ERROR: UndefVarError: Optimizer not defined
Stacktrace:
[1] top-level scope
@ REPL[3]:1
But i have already installed the latest version of Jump and ipopt.
Any ideas? Thanks!

[mre] please...

Please include a snippet which can reproduce your error (see comment above). Without any necessary details, it seems like you did not create the optimizer object yet, which I assume is supposed to be an instanced subtype of <:AbstractOptimzer, like using GLPK;optimizer = GLPK.Optimizer(), as taken from the JumP tutorial. This is a guess, though, as a reproducible example is required for any type of certain answer.

Your error has Model(Ipopt,Optimizer). It needs to be Model(Ipopt.Optimizer).
Note the period . instead of the comma ,.
